# Single record of greatest n per group from a table with three identifiers

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in which each record is a single purchase made by a single client.

Purchases can be made in different categories of product and different geographical areas (each of these is a single field).

I can count how many purchases each client has in each combination of product/area like this

```
Select client_id, product_id, zone_id, COUNT(purchase_id)
Group by client_id, product_id, zone_id
```

From this I would like to get a table where each record is the client, product and zone with the highest number of purchases. So only one row per client.

How would I go about doing this?

I think I might be able to do it by using NOT EXISTS where there is no record with the same three identifiers and higher COUNT, but as this is part of a much larger query I'm afraid of performance issues.

I also figure I might be able to concatenate the three identifiers into a single one, but I need those identifiers to be in separate fields as I need them for a join in another query this will be part of.

Comment: What is MySQL version? show the output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: 10.0.30-MariaDB

Comment: Too old version, it supports neither CTE nor window functions. Is the version upgrade possible? If not then use your query as a source, group it by client and find greatest purchases amount. Then join this to another copy of your query and select the whole row. Alternatively emulate ROW_NUMBER using user-defined variables and get only 1st row per client.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Generate a temp table with the 3 columns plus count as you mentioned.

Step 2:  Apply a groupwise-max algorithm.  Either follow the link you have or check out [*Groupwise-Max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)